# Jasmine: Real function being called after spyOn with function reference

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, spy

I have an angular service.  Inside this service I have an object with a function, that references another function on the service. (Code below)

I want to use Jasmine (1.3) to spy on my service function, to verify that when the object's function gets called, it actually calls the real function.

**My problem:  After calling spyOn, the real function is still being called.**

FooService.js

```
angular.module('foo').service("FooService", function() {
     var self = this;

     this.fooFunction = function() {
         console.log("Foo function is being called");
     }

     this.bar = {
         barFunction : self.fooFunction
     }
});
```

FooService-spec.js

```
describe("Testing FooService", function() {
     var service;

     beforeEach(inject(function(_FooService_) {
         service = _FooService_;
     }));

     describe("Test bar object", function() {
        it("should call fooFunction when bar.barFunction is called", function() {
             spyOn(service, "fooFunction");
             service.bar.barFunction();
             expect(service.fooFunction).toHaveBeenCalled();
         });
     });
 });
```

I have found that if I change FooServce.js to the following, this all works though:

FooService - Working

```
angular.module('foo').service("FooService", function() {
     var self = this;

     this.fooFunction = function() {
         console.log("Real function is being called");
     }

     this.bar = {
         barFunction : function() {
             return self.fooFunction();
         }
     }
 });
```

What part of JavaScript / Angular / Jasmine am I failing to understand in the first example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`spyOn` operates by replacing the value of an object property with a different value. When you do `spyOn(service, "fooFunction");` you're doing something like

```
var realFunc = service.fooFunction;
service.fooFunction = function() {
    doSpyStuff();
    return realFunc.apply(this, arguments);
}
```

Note that this doesn't modify the value `service.fooFunction`. It actually modifies `service` -- namely, one of the properties of `service` is now a totally different function. This replacement will only affect the `fooFunction` property of `service`. If you're not accessing a property of `service`, you're certainly not on your way to invoking the spy function.

So let's apply this knowledge to your case. In your test, you are accessing a property of `service.bar`. While `service.bar.barFunction` and `service.fooFunction` were originally the same value, `service` has had its `fooFunction` property replaced by the spy, while (very importantly) `service.bar` has not had any of its properties mutated by `spyOn`. When you call `service.bar.barFunction()`, you directly invoke the real function, and have no connection to the spy that lives on `service`'s `fooFunction` property.

By contrast, when you do `barFunction: function() { return self.fooFunction(); }` as an anonymous function, you actually *are* accessing the spy property value on `service`, because here `self` happens to be `service`, so `self.fooFunction` is `service.fooFunction`, which is the property that holds a spy replacement value.

Comment: I figured it was something along these lines.   Anyway to test these then?

Comment: @Mistrog You spy on properties, not on function values, so you'll have to spy on the exact object/property you want to call. Alternatively, use the pattern present in your second example that works.